# NSStream FTP resume file upload after NSStreamEventErrorOccurred

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ftp

This code works fine, but im trying to implement a resume action after an NSStreamEventErrorOccurred, for example after internet connection lost.

What i have done is to save the number of _totalBytesSend and redo the upload only with the remaining bytes, but im facing that only the remaining bytes will be stored instead of the complete file.

I couldn't able to figure out how to resume file upload or if is there a way to merge the streams when an error ocurred?

```
- (void)enviar:(NSData *)aDatos pathArchivo:(NSString *)path bytesEnviados:(size_t *)aBytesEnviados
{
    BOOL success;
    NSURL *url;

    long liBytesInicio = aBytesEnviados;
    NSData *newData = [aDatos subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(liBytesInicio, [aDatos length] - liBytesInicio)];

    _currentBytesEnviados = aBytesEnviados;
    _currentDatos = aDatos;
    _currentPathArchivos = path;

    assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap send twice in a row!
    assert(self.fileStream == nil);         // ditto

    // First get and check the URL.

    url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:[Sesion sharedSesion].configuracion.servidorFTP];
    success = (url != nil);

    if (success) {
        // Add the last part of the file name to the end of the URL to form the final
        // URL that we're going to put to.

        url = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFStringRef)path, false));
        success = (url != nil);
    }

    // If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.


    // Open a stream for the file we're going to send.  We do not open this stream;
    // NSURLConnection will do it for us.

    self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:newData];
    assert(self.fileStream != nil);

    [self.fileStream open];

    // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.

    self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url));

    assert(self.networkStream != nil);


    success = [self.networkStream setProperty:[Sesion sharedSesion].configuracion.cuentaFTP forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
    assert(success);
    success = [self.networkStream setProperty:[Sesion sharedSesion].configuracion.passwordFTP forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
    assert(success);    

    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream open];

    // Tell the UI we're sending.

}

- (void)detenerEnvio:(NSString *)estado {
    if (self.networkStream != nil) {
        [self.networkStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        self.networkStream.delegate = nil;
        [self.networkStream close];
        self.networkStream = nil;


    }
    if (self.fileStream != nil) {
        [self.fileStream close];
        self.fileStream = nil;
    }

    [self envioDetenido:estado];
}

- (void)continuaEnvio
{
    double delayInSeconds = 12.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        NSLog(@"After Delay code");
        if ([self.networkStream streamStatus] != NSStreamStatusOpen) {

            PutController *ftp = [[PutController alloc] init];
            ftp.delegate = self;
            _currentBytesEnviados = _totalBytesSend;//_currentDatos.length;
            NSLog(@"Current total bytes ** %i", _currentBytesEnviados);
            [ftp enviar:_currentDatos pathArchivo:_currentPathArchivos bytesEnviados:_currentBytesEnviados];
            self.ftpController = ftp;

        }

    });
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
// An NSStream delegate callback that's called when events happen on our
// network stream.
{
#pragma unused(aStream)
    assert(aStream == self.networkStream);

    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
            [self iniciarEnvio:@"Abriendo conexion"];
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
            assert(NO);     // should never happen for the output stream
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {

            // If we don't have any data buffered, go read the next chunk of data.

            if (self.bufferOffset == self.bufferLimit) {
                NSInteger   bytesRead;

                bytesRead = [self.fileStream read:self.buffer maxLength:kSendBufferSize];

                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    [self detenerEnvio:@"Error al leer archivo."];
                } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
                    [self detenerEnvio:nil];
                    break;
                } else {
                    self.bufferOffset = 0;
                    self.bufferLimit  = bytesRead;
                }

            }

            // If we're not out of data completely, send the next chunk.

            if (self.bufferOffset != self.bufferLimit) {

                    NSInteger   bytesWritten;
                    bytesWritten = [self.networkStream write:&self.buffer[self.bufferOffset] maxLength:self.bufferLimit - self.bufferOffset];
                    assert(bytesWritten != 0);
                    if (bytesWritten == -1) {
                        [self detenerEnvio:@"Error al escribir."];
                    } else {
                        self.bufferOffset += bytesWritten;
                        _totalBytesSend += bytesWritten;

                        [self actualizaEnvio:bytesWritten];
                    }


            }
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
            //**** Here is where im trying to resume the upload *****
            [self detenerEnvio:@"Error al abrir el stream."];
            [self continuaEnvio];

        } break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
            // ignore
        } break;
        default: {
            assert(NO);
        } break;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!